# Testing fallback import in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Using Python 3. There's a module used by my application that should be installed by `pip`, but in case the user does not have the correct module installed, I want to provide a fallback module.

I'd like to unit test this without having to switch environments. Hence the following:

File a.py

```
"""
This module would, under ideal circumstances, be installed with pip
but maybe not...
"""
class Foo():

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        return "This is the module we'd like to import"
```

File b.py

```
"""
This is my own fallback module
"""
class Foo():

    @staticmethod
    def test():
        return "This is the fallback module"
```

File c.py

```
try:
    from sandbox.a import Foo
except ImportError:
    from sandbox.b import Foo

"""This is the module in my app that would actually use Foo"""
```

Here's the test, d.py

```
import sys

def test_it():
    sys.modules['a'] = None
    import sandbox.c as c
    s = c.Foo.test()
    assert s == "This is the fallback module"
```

This fails with AssertionError

```
E       AssertionError: assert 'This is the ...ike to import' == 'This is the fallback module'
E         - This is the module we'd like to import
E         + This is the fallback module

sandbox/d.py:8: AssertionError
```

What is the correct way to test this, so that I make sure users never get an ImportError (if they don't have module `a.py` installed) and they have functionality provided by fallback module `b.py` in such an event?

Comment: have you tried something like this: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/31/advanced-python-how-to-dynamically-load-modules-or-classes/

Comment: It looks like you do have module a installed when you run the test. I don't think setting `sys.modules['a'] = None` is sufficient to remove it.

Comment: It turns out my MWE doesn't accurately represent my problem, but since @Sanya's answer does solve the problem as presented, and since this might be helpful to others, I'm accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have the following structure:

```
- dir sandbox
-- file a.py
-- file b.py
-- file c.py
- file d.py
```

I tried replace `sys.modules['a'] = None` to `sys.modules['sandbox.a'] = None` and this works.